# NSWorkspace openFile: randomly brings focus back to my app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Within my Cocoa app, I call NSWorkspace's openFile: method to open some file with its default application.

Sometimes this works just fine, and the other application gets focus, as it should.

But alas, sometimes (the occurrence of which seems to be totally random), after the focus goes briefly to the other application, it goes quickly back to my Cocoa app. This is unwanted.

Any ideas what the causes could be?

Note: I have also tried the openFile:withApplication:andDeactivate:, passing YES to the last argument. This doesn't work either. The strange random occurrences of focus going back to my Cocoa app persist.

Comment: What else is your application doing? Maybe there's another process going on that is forcing focus back to your app.

Comment: Well, can I somehow configure the debugger to break only after openFile has been executed, *and* break only within my own code? (This would help isolate the problem, as none of my own code lines should get executed after openFile:)

Comment: If I can configure my debugger in such a way, it should thus randomly break after openFile within my own code. (Since my problem is occurring only randomly.)

Comment: From the top of my head, I cannot really think of any reason why I would programmatically someplace else have forced the main window to become key.. but still, the debugger might be able to tell me otherwise.

Comment: For some reasons, I'm unable to reproduce this issue anymore. I wonder if it was just a temporary issue with the window server or something. Hmmm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce this now. Not sure what the problem was.